# teb local planner installation

Tags: ros, installation, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to install and use the teb_local_planner in ROS hydro by following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Setup%20and%20test%20Optimization

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-teb-local-planner
[sudo] password for powerbot67:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-teb-local-planner
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ rosdep install teb_local_planner

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource teb_local_planner
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226880/teb-local-planner-installation/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaict, `teb_local_planner` has not been released into Hydro. See the [wiki/teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) page (notice no `Hydro` button in the version rocker), and [status_page/hydro.html?q=teb_local_planner](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/hydro.html?q=teb_local_planner).

Options:

- upgrade to Indigo
- try to install `teb_local_planner` from source on Hydro: this will probably fail (but it depends on the differences between the Hydro and Indigo+ versions of the navigation stack and any other dependencies it might have)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thanks for your reply @gvdhoorn. I'll try installing teb_local_planner from source in the next few days.